# @Mock domain objects in unit testing in grails listOrderBy dynamic finder throws an exception

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, dynamic-finders

I am writing a unit test for a grails controller. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
@TestFor(MyController)
@Mock([MyDomain])
class MyControllerTests {

    void testController() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is how the domain object looks like:

```
class MyDomain {
    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false)
        parent(nullable: true)
    }

    static belongsTo = Industry

    static hasMany = [children: Industry]

    Industry parent
    String name
}
```

The method in the controller I am testing calls this GORM dynamic method:

```
MyDomain.listOrderByParent()
```

The test fails when execution hits this line and the exception is not making much sense to me since the @Mock annotation should have added all the dynamic methods:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot compare com.stuff.MyDomain with value 'com.stuff.MyDomain : 1' and com.stuff.MyDomain with value 'com.stuff.MyDomain : 4'
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery$_executeQuery_closure63_closure155.doCall(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:78)
```

The controller works fine when running the grails app. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please attach the implementation of the test method?

Answer (score 0):

You may mock the Industry domain object
 as well:

```
@Mock([MyDomain, Industry])
```